# Diagram 9, shows a four-digit passcode '0131' set by San on his smartphone. How many different passcodes can be formed?

Tags: permutations

Diagram 9, shows a four-digit passcode '0131' set by San on his smartphone.

[Diagram 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw5H4.png)

He wants to reset the passcode such that the new passcode cannot consists of digit 1 followed by digit 3.
How many different passcodes can be formed?
I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Always better to add your attempt.

Comment: As total is $10^4$ we count which cannot be formed and subtract. the forms are $13**,\,*13*,\,**13,\,1313$ which gives $99+100+99+1=299$ codes can't be formed. Did I get the question right? Or $1*3*,\,1**3,\,*1*3$ are forbidden as well? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin   Thanks for your answer. So, different passcodes can be formed is $10^4-299=9701$